# Angular: trying to submit coordinates array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a geolocation api, and I'm having a hard time submitting two coordinates to be merged into an array.
In my mongoose schema, i Have this:

```
geolocation: { 
 type: { type: String, default:"Point" }, 
 coordinates: [Number], 
},
```

In my index.html, i have this input

```
 input ng-model='values[0]' type='text' input ng-model='values[1]' 
 type='text'
```

In my controller, i'm trying

```
function mainController($scope, $http) {
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.values=[];

$scope.createLocation = function() {
        $scope.formData.geolocation.coordinates = new Array(2);
        $scope.formData.geolocation.coordinates.push({
            0: $scope.values[0],
            1: $scope.values[1]
        });
        $http.post('/api/places/:location', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another                       
                $scope.locations = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
```

However, when I submit, I get the error

```
 Cannot set property 'coordinates' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is coming from your angular code of course, so `$scope.formData.geolocation` is undefined ad probably incorrectly named. Perhaps you forgot to create the `geolocation` property on `formData`. You might also note that a format like `{  0: $scope.values[0], 1: $scope.values[1]  }` is not in line with what your backend schema is expecting though. Using "names of keys" is not actually an "array", and is a misconception common to people with a PHP background. Since that language has some really odd concepts of what an "array" is. But it's a "front end" error, and not "back end" right now.

Comment: Ok i figured as much that the error was on frontend. However, all other fields of formData werent defined and work fine. How should i created geolocation on it? And how should I fix my array input?

Comment: What I mean if that if you want to create a "nested property" on an object, you need to create the "parent property" first. So `$scope.formData.geolocation = {}; $scope.formData.geolocation.coordinates = new Array(2);` or even `$scope.formData.geolocation = { coordinates = new Array(2) };`

Comment: Or even more to the point `$scope.formData.geolocation = { coordinates: $scope.values };` to avoid the misconception of "array format" as I also mentioned earlier. These are basics of JavaScript object construction that you really should acquaint yourself with.

Comment: That was indeed straight to the point. Thanks so much!
You should post that as answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Neil-Lunn, the error was in the frontend, and

```
$scope.formData.geolocation = { coordinates: $scope.values };
```

fixed it.